# MongoDB indexing multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

document

```
_id: ..
user_id (index): User1
title: Test
details (index): { gener: 'Fantasy', author: 'Author01', language: 'test', interest: 1 }
filters (index): ['black', 'red', 'green', 'medium', .... (can contain more than 40 values)]
```

Here i'm trying to index 3 fields in MongoDB collection

```
user_id (holds only string as a value)
details (object of 4 key-value pairs)
filters (array which holds more than 40 values)
```

Indexing this way in mongodb works well? If not, what is the better way to index such collections?

Comment: [MongoDB supports compound indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/)

Comment: indexes depend upon your  query , if you want to query with single filed or multiple field with object just use this way . create single field index (user_id:1) or create multiple filed with object (user_id:1,'detail.gender':1), my suggestion dont use index in array field when more record in array, see this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Answer (score 0):

$text performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with a text index.
Example:

```
  db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

[reference here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)